# GooglePlay Console: App doesn't have any in-app products yet.

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, billing

Okay, I have previously added in-app purchase to apps but this time the warning doesn't go away. In console i get this message "App doesn't have any in-app products yet."

In Google Play Console, I have uploaded an app, i am using [Android-in-app-Billing-v3-light](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3). It's an in-app billing library from github. I have added permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
```

This warning doesn't seem to go away. What i am doing wrong? Did google play change it's requirement? Why it's not allowing me get past this screen or warning. Most questions asked had some error with permission but i have added permission. Also published the app in alpha.

[image]

With test id it's showing.

[image]

Comment: Umm, do you really want to use a 3rd party in app billing library, rather than Google's own?  That sounds like a great way to get owned.  Especially if you have the gradle to pull latest rather than a specific version.  This is something I wouldn't even remotely consider adding another layer in between.  Especially when the authors are some random Russian company I've never heard of before.

Comment: And the latest commit was almost a year ago.  Yeah, that sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Thanks for reply @GabeSechan, it was easy to implement that's why i chose it. I even tried with uploading app with google's in-app billing. I am having same issue the screen is stuck to "your app doesn't have any in-app billing product'

Comment: I believe the library is safe, the library is open source so everyone can check the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I found what was causing this issue, Google has updated their terms and services and now you need to create merchant account before you enable in-app purchases.

please create your merchant account, check the screenshot

the link is here https://play.google.com/apps/publish

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After the android new update, playstore will show you error when you add Billing permission in your AndroidManifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>. <---- Don't add this in the manifest file
```

Instead, you need to add a new line in your android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
....
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0'. <---- Add this line in android/app/build.gradle
 }
```

Comment: now you should add - implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:6.1.0"