# Google Play Console - can't create subscriptions even tough closed testing App was uploaded

Tags: android, google-play-console

I can't create subscriptions in Google Play Console. It says "Your app doesn't have any subscriptions yet" and there is only the button "Upload new APK" whih leads to closed testing.

But I already did that and it was approved! What the hell does Google still want??

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52174945/googleplay-console-app-doesnt-have-any-in-app-products-yet

Comment: I'l check out if that will solve it and tell it afterwards. Will probably have to upload and wait again. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yeah check out my answer @holger.meyer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upload an APK with implemented Billing Library into closed testing, after review you can create subscriptions. Don't forget to add a test user